# Plot with max min and arbitrary value

Tags: plotting

I have a list of values for example {{1.15579, 0.844208}, {1.15876, 1.12875, 0.841237, 0.871245, 0.844401, 1.1556, 1.07366, 0.926342}} and I would like to plot in the same graph, for each list, the max, the min and some special values which in this case would be 1.10 and 1.12. I tried using  `BoxWhiskerChart[{{1.15579, 0.844208}, {1.15876, 1.12875, 0.841237, 0.871245, 0.844401, 1.1556, 1.07366, 0.926342}}, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thick, White]}}, ChartLabels -> {"t1", "t2"}`, the problem is that with that I can only print the mean or the median, I instead need to plot a special number that I computed before. Can I use `BoxWhiskerChart` or is there something else I can use?

Comment: "special" does not seem awfully specific to me, could you specify a bit more? Is something like `ListPlot[({Min[#], Max[#], special} & /@ {{1.15579, 
      0.844208}, {1.15876, 1.12875, 0.841237, 0.871245, 0.844401, 
      1.1556, 1.07366, 0.926342}, {1}})\[Transpose]]` a solution for you?

Comment: Also, what type of data do you want to show? Are you looking for something like `BoxWhiskerChart`?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like `BoxWhiskerChart`, I don't really need the othe values except the min and the max but I do need to plug in manually the special value (that is usually different) at t1 and t2. Also if possible I would like to keep the rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would show work for you?

```
Show[BoxWhiskerChart[{{1.15579, 0.844208}, {1.15876, 1.12875, 
0.841237, 0.871245, 0.844401, 1.1556, 1.07366, 0.926342}}, 
ChartLabels -> {"t1", "t2"}], 
ListPlot[{1.1, 1.12}, 
PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```
data = {{1.15579, 0.844208}, {1.15876, 1.12875, 0.841237, 0.871245, 
   0.844401, 1.1556, 1.07366, 0.926342}};

p = Last@data;

{q1, q2} = First@data;

Show[
 ListPlot[p, Filling -> Bottom, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.5}],
 Plot[{Mean[p], q1, q2}, {x, 1, Length@p},
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Blue, 
    Directive[Black, Dotted]},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]

Comment: The first and the second set of data are all for time t1 and t2. I do need to keep them all together given the time.